# file.write ints/floats in python for binary files without using struct

Tags: python, file, struct, io, binary

I have a file open in binary mode and I want to output ints and doubles (np.float64) to it. Pretty much every binary file tutorial I've seen says to use the struct module:

```
fout.write(struct.pack('i', np.int32(pca.components_.shape[0])))
```

If I don't use struct.pack, the operation is still legal and I still seem to be able to read out the bytes if I open the file in a C program later as the correct int values.

```
fout.write(np.int32(pca.components_.shape[0]))
```

Is struct.pack absolutely necessary? What happens if you write a number value to a binary file without packing? Thanks.

Comment: For a single (or an array of) sized numeric types, like those from `numpy`, then this should be fine. `struct` is useful when you have more complicated data-types, i.e. structs...

Comment: notice, if you had a *python* `int` object, say `i = 42`, then you would have to do something like `fout.write(i.to_bytes(4, 'little'))`

Comment: So numpy types convert automatically, but python natives do not? Does this work for np.float64?

Comment: I can only assume that `numpy` objects, scaler and array, implement the buffer protocol, which is what is required for `.write` to accept the object. Otherwise, `.write` will throw an error.

Comment: See [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) But yes, vanilla Python numeric types don't implement this, you have to explicitely convert them to an object that does. Built-in types that *do* implement the buffer-protocol are `bytes`, `bytearray`, `array.array`, and `memoryview` objects.